# Looking for VDSL2 modem that can work without NAT

Tags: networking, internet, adsl, isp, adsl-router

All ADSL/VDSL providers here (The Netherlands) provide modems with integrated router. Not only that, but they put in their own firmware, so that you can do next to nothing with it. With my old ADSL line, I modded a speedtouch 546 to do DHCP spoofing, so that it gives out its WAN IP, but that modem has no VDSL2 support, so it is no longer usable.

So, I'm looking for a VDSL2 modem that has no NAT, or has an option to turn it off, to simply serve the WAN IP to my Linux machine.

Any advice is welcome.

Would the [Thomson 789](http://www.speedtouch.nl/docs/Datasheets/TG789vn_Datasheet.pdf) have such support?

Answer (score 0):

The 'BT Openreach' VDSL2 modem that British Telecom supplied for my [BT Infinity](http://www.bt.com/infinity) FTTC VDSL2 service is a rebranded [Huawei HG612](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=2394&directoryId=3870&treeId=3015), if that's any help.

It has two LAN ports, one of which has a sticker over it, saying 'not in use'.  I am not aware of any web interface that it may have.  I use it along with a Netgear WNR3500L router running Tomato.

Comment: Does that mean it indeed does give out its WAN IP to the device you connect to its LAN port? And no webinterface? How do I config the username/password and line properties then?

Comment: @Halfgaar: Yes, my NAT router receives the public WAN IP address from the BT Openreach modem. I assume that the BT version of this modem has special firmware with the standard BT DSL username and there is no password needed. The supplied 'BT Infinity hub' router has the username hardcoded too. As I use my own router instead, I need to use the same standard username in its setup, along with any password. I guess that the BT Openreach modem has the web interface disabled as it is not needed, as it is already hard-configured for the BT Infinity service.

Comment: Sounds kind of like a construction I had with a previous cable modem (motorolla surfboard). It gave its wan IP to your PC/router, but still had a web interface which could be accessed by going to 192.168.100.1, even though that address was not in your subnet; the router recognized it as special. I guess it wouldn't have worked if 192.168.100.0/24 was your LAN.

Comment: @Halfgaar: Are you sure that the supplied modem/router does not have a 'DMZ host' setting?

Comment: Yes; when I say you can co next to nothing, I mean it :)